# Cannot run app in debug mode from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I cannot run my app in debug mode in Android Studio. Sometimes it says the problem is with `localhost:8601`, and other times I get the output below:

```
Client not ready yet.
Client not ready yet.
Client not ready yet.
Client not ready yet.
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.test.myapp/.activity.SplashActivity }
```

Comment: Is issue solved? can u confirm if its not connecting debugger or breakpoints never hit?

Comment: @Nasir no not resolved. it's not connecting

Comment: @Nasir no it's not resolved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.
my phone setting should set on **MTP** mode and nothing else.
debugger connects to my phone after this change.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and fixed now. Here is what i did which might help u

1. Confirm the exact problem, Is it that debugger is not able to connect or breakpoints not hit. TO confirm this put breakpoint in MainActivity. Also application would be waiting for debugger, just check if it stopped waiting or any console logs. Also just check if debugger shows pause button
2. Check ur gradle config and make sure apk has symbols. (Debug release)

In my case issue was 1st and got it resolved. Hope this might help else pls ignore

Comment: I do not get your second solution

Comment: @Kenji edited my answer, pls check point (1) and make sure that debugger has connected and u see pause button to pause debug

Comment: In my case, the problem is come from Launch Options:
I have set to **Specified Activity** and in AndroidManifest.xml does not have launcher <intent-filter> for that activity

So, set launch options to **Default Activity** or add
`            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>`
to startup activity